# Bash - store which elements of an array failed to execute some command

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
read -r -p "Enter the filenames: " -a arr

for filenames in "${arr[@]}"; do
   if [[ -e "${filenames}" ]]; then
        echo "${filenames} file exists (no override)"
   else
        cp -n ~/Documents/library/normal.py "${filenames}"
   fi
done
```

Suppose, I've `B.py D.py` in a folder.

When I run this script in the same folder and write `A.py B.py C.py D.py` (undefined number of inputs)
 Files named `A.py C.py` are copied successfully.

Whereas for `B.py D.py`, it shows `B.py file exists (no override)` and `D.py file exists (not override)` respectively.

I want to store elements `which did worked` and `which didn't work` in separate arrays from main array `${arr[@]}`

```bash
arr=('A.py' 'B.py' 'C.py' 'D.py')
didworked=('A.py' 'C.py')
notworked=('B.py' 'D.py')
```

How can i do that? Any suggestions, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just append the filename to the corresponding arrays at the right points:

```
#!/bin/bash
files=('A.py' 'B.py' 'C.py' 'D.py')
files_err=()
files_ok=()
for f in "${files[@]}"; do
   if [[ -e "$f" ]]; then
        echo "$f file exists (no override)"
        files_err+=("$f")
   else
        if cp -n ~/Documents/library/normal.py "$f"; then
            files_ok+=("$f")
        else
            # copy failed, cp should have printed an error message
            files_err+=("$f")
        fi
   fi
done
```

(I wouldn't use `filenames` as the loop variable in that for, it's only one filename (at a time), not many.)

Comment: On the systems I have, that implement `-n` for `cp`, `cp -n` does not print a diagnostic message if the destination file exists.

Comment: @Kusalananda, nor does it return with error status, yep. They had the explicit check there to see if the destination file existed already, so that deals with that. The check on `cp` is mostly for completeness since the copy could fail for other reasons too. Probably not too commonly, and anything that came up would probably prevent all the copies. Like the disk being full or whatever.

Comment: Hmm... GNU `cp -n` does not return a non-zero exit status if the destination exists, but other implementations do (tested FreeBSD and macOS). So it's still useful.

Comment: @Kusalananda, ah, ok. I only quickly tested GNU. And it's enough that it doesn't, since it means the explicit check on the destination file is necessary. If we knew `cp -n` returns non-zero when the destination exists, the `-e` test could be dropped.

Comment: `cp -n` is probably not standardized for the simple reason that `test -e` already exists.

Comment: @Kusalananda, or because they can't agree on what the exit status would be ... `test -e` can't replace `cp -n` or `mv -n`, though. There's that time-of-check-to-time-of-use problem there, a file could appear after the `test -e` was done but before the copy happens. But `cp -n` can use `O_CREAT | O_EXCL` on the `open()` call to get an error at the time the file is actually created, so it's actually safe.